# Two dimensional associative array in PHP

Tags: php

In my code I'm getting data (three columns) from a sql db and I want to store the rows in an associative PHP array. The array must be multi-dimensional because I want to use the row id from the database as a key so that i can fetch values like this:

> $products["f84jjg"]["name"]
>
> $products["245"]["code"]

I've tried using the following code but it doesn't work:

```
while ($row = mysql_fetch_row($sqlresult))
{
    $products = array($row[0] => array(
            name => $row[1], 
            code => $row[2]
        )
    );
}
```

Also, how should I reference the key if it is taken from a variable? What I want to do is:

```
$productName = $products[$thisProd]["name"];
```

Will this work?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

This should do it, assuming `row[0]`'s contents is a unique identifier (else you could override a row):

```
while($row = mysql_fetch_row($sqlresult)) {
    $products[$row[0]] = array(
        'name' => $row[1], 
        'code' => $row[2]
    );
}
```

You need to put quotes around the array keys, and you were creating an array of array of arrays.

Also note you could use [`mysql_fetch_assoc`](http://www.php.net/mysql_fetch_assoc) instead of `mysql_fetch_row`, which would give you the array keys as the column names, which would make this much easier/cleaner:

```
while($row = mysql_fetch_assoc($sqlresult)) {
    $products[$row['myidcolumn']] = $row;
}
```

After you do this, the code you described would work.